# Magento Re- Indexing Issue

Tags: magento

[image]I am facing one issue in Magento. I am having one Magento store with multi website functionality which containing approx 4500 products. I want to re-indexing product.

I had import 4500 product by csv through magento default functionality. after importing product the changes is not showing on front side so i went to index management and i found there are two indexes are in processing status

1 Product Attributes  2  Product Flat Data

I had already done following steps:

1 try to re-index it from admin side system->index management

2 try to do manually by calling php script

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask( 0 );
Mage :: app( "default" );
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_flat');
$process->reindexAll();
```

OR

```
$indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {
    $process->reindexEverything();
}
```

Also change the var/locks folder permission to 777 and also rename that folder  and also try to delete the .lock file which was created in this lock folder but not got the solution.

I am not having SSH rights. So is there any other solution which will help me to solve re-indexing problem.

Comment: What is the actual problem? You've mentioned several ways which you have tried to re-index, but you haven't actually mentioned why it is that any of the methods so-far have been insufficient.

Comment: Hello Will,I had import 4500 product by csv through magento default functionality. after importing product the changes is not showing on front side so i went to index management and i found there are two indexes are in processing status

1 Product Attributes  2  Product Flat Data

Comment: when indexes are stuck in the "Processing" state for a long time, it is possible that the permissions on the lockfiles in magento's var directory are wrong. Magento lists indexes as "Processing" whenever it can't obtain a lock, without bothering to check the reason for the failure. The most common reason for failing to acquire a lock, other than the index-processing actually being locked, is the locks having been created by a different user account. (for example, if `cron` is run as `root`, while magento is normally accessed by the `apache` user). Ensure magento has write access to the locks.

Comment: thanks will, but now what to do to solve this issue i am facing it last two days and it makes me very frustrated  I also rename the var/lock folder and there are two files is there in index_process_4.lock & index_process_1.lock

Comment: you renamed the `var/lock` folder and the two locks were re-created in the old location?

Comment: yes it's created in var/lock automatically

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16815/discussion-between-will-palmer-and-darshan-dodiya)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**

There are references to inexisting/deleted products in catalog_product_flat_% tables.

**Solution**

Try to truncate ´catalog_product_flat_%´ tables (catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2, catalog_product_flat_3 etc.) in MySQL console or via phpMyAdmin:

```
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_1´;
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_2´;
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_3´;
```

Then reindex.

Comment: wouldn't that cause the indexes to fail silently, rather than to be perpetually marked as "processing"?

Comment: I have to do indexing without affecting DB - Palanikumar

Comment: @Palanikumar : If I run these command, will that delete my product catalog or there will be no effect on products which are already added.

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE: While the below answer has, in my experience, been relevant to this type of issue, it does not appear to be the cause of the situation currently experienced by the asker**

`Processing` means one of two things:

- The indexes may actually still be runnning, in which case, sit back and wait for them to finish. Magento indexing can take a very long time (for 4500 products, "hours" is possible, depending on the server).
- An indexer process may have died, leaving stale locks behind. Meanwhile, the dead indexer may have been run by a different user. The most common case is `cron` being incorrectly configured to run the indexer as `root`, or a normal user account, rather than as the same user as is used by the website (eg: `apache` or `www`).

All that `Processing` really means is "Magento failed to acquire a lock for these indexer jobs". The first case is trivial and uninteresting. Wait a couple of hours, and if the **same** indexers are still listed as `Processing`, then you may have the second case.

Check the permissions of the lock files, found under `var/locks` in your magento root. Are they owned by the same user as the web server is running as? If not, **and you are absolutely certain that the indexes are no longer running**, it is safe to delete the locks. The next step is to find out why the locks had the wrong permissions in the first place. That is a conversation which might be better had with your host, if you don't have `ssh` access.

Answer (score 1):

The errors from the indexer will be caught and not logged by default. The typical workaround is to use the CLI re-index tool; which will be very verbose with any errors.

Eg.

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex ...
```

But given you don't have SSH access - you can either look at the `indexer.php` file to see how they generate the errors, or you could just launch a `shell_exec` or `exec` from a web-based PHP script that would emulate the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reindex `catalog_product_flat` index process. After spending a day and trying several solutions on the Internet. i was able to fix the issue. Below is the steps.

1. Create a clone of the Magento Db which is facing the indexing issue.
2. Dump the database into the newly created db.
3. truncate the table `catalog_product_flat_1` for single store and for multiple store there will be multiple table `catalog_product_flat_*` where `*` is the store id. Here truncate all that table.
4. point the mangento running instance to the newly created database and configure the databse, so that site is functioning normally.
5. Now run the command `php document_root/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat` or try reindexing from Admin. `php document_root/shell/indexer.php --reindexall` for reindexing all the process.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, when creating new customer group I was unable to reindex prices.

Found the solution here http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-resolve-magento-reindexing-errors-in-your-magento-store/

Here the procedure:

1. Locate var/locks directory and remove all files under this directory. This will clear all the locks for re-indexing to take place again.
2. Now, login to your MysQSL/phpMyAdmin to run the following MySQL query (Ensure that your have taken full backup before committing this MySQL query)

   DELETE cpop.* FROM catalog_product_option_price AS cpop
       INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
       ON cpo.option_id = cpop.option_id
       WHERE
       cpo.type = 'checkbox' OR
       cpo.type = 'radio' OR
       cpo.type = 'drop_down';

   ```
   DELETE cpotp.* FROM catalog_product_option_type_price AS cpotp
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value AS cpotv
   ON cpotv.option_type_id = cpotp.option_type_id
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
   ON cpotv.option_id = cpo.option_id
   WHERE
   cpo.type <> 'checkbox' AND
   cpo.type <> 'radio' AND
   cpo.type <> 'drop_down';
   ```
3. Log back in to your Magento Admin panel and go to System tab > Index Management hit index again and you will notice no such errors will appear again. You can follow these same steps again if re-indexing stops in future to resolve `Magento` `ReIndexing` issues.