# Catalog Search Index Stuck on Processing

Tags: magento

Catalog Search Indexing is continuously running and I'm not sure why it's doing this or how to stop it.  [I tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470855/magento-re-indexing-issue) but it didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try is simply empty that table. Using MySQL/PhpMyAdmin run the SQL command:

```
truncate catalogsearch_fulltext;
```

Then run try refreshing the index again.

Beyond this, you may want to extend the maximum time out in your php.ini to something like 36000 and try to truncate and refresh the index again.

If even this doesn't work you could reindex using the command line over SSH using the command (from your Magento root directory):

```
php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```